# How do I use variables in the rename funciton (c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, directory, rename

I am trying to let the user name a file to be moved from one folder to another using the rename function this is my code:

```
string c;
          cout<<"What file should be moved?"<<endl;
          getline(cin,c);
          char oldname[] = "D:\\subasta\\"+ c +".txt";
          char newname[] = "D:\\subasta\\open\\"+ c +".txt";
```

The problem is that I can´t use the variable string c.
Any alternatives?

Comment: What aren't `oldname` and `newname` `string`'s like `c` is?

Comment: "_The problem is that I can´t use the variable string c_" But.. You can. Why do you think, that you can't?

Comment: Make a [mcve]. There are two different `rename` functions in C++. [std::filesystem::rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) and [std::rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename). You haven't even shown much enough for us to see which one you tried using.

Comment: You could use [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmtlib.github.io): `auto oldname = fmt::format("D:\\subasta\\{}.txt", c)`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It give me this error in this line of code                                   
 char oldname[] = "D:\\subasta\\"+ c +".txt"; error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

Comment: Or as string: `string oldname = "D:\\subasta\\"+ c +".txt";`

Comment: Use  `std::string` instead of `char[]`. That works with `std::filesystem::rename`. If you use `std::rename` you need to call the `std::string`s `.c_str()` function to get a `const char*`

Comment: @MasterWorks There can be plenty of reasons for code not compiling, instead of "can't use the variable".. So was curious about why you jumped to said conclusion, instead of just stating that you get this error, and asking how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two versions:

```
#include <cstdio> // std::rename
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string c;
    std::string oldname = "D:\\subasta\\"+ c +".txt";
    std::string newname = "D:\\subasta\\open\\" + c + ".txt";
    std::rename(oldname.c_str(), newname.c_str());
}
```

```
#include <filesystem> // std::filesystem::rename
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string c;
    std::string oldname = "D:\\subasta\\"+ c +".txt";
    std::string newname = "D:\\subasta\\open\\" + c + ".txt";
    std::filesystem::rename(oldname, newname);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally worked!

Comment: @MasterWorks Glad to hear it! You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this.

```
string c;         //your original string
char variable[];  //your convert variable
strcpy(variable, c.c_str());

          cout<<"What file should be moved?"<<endl;
          getline(cin,c);
          char oldname[] = "D:\\subasta\\"+ variable +".txt";
          char newname[] = "D:\\subasta\\open\\"+ variable +".txt";
```